# Applying a regex to build 3 pandas columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have this function that applies regex and returns the splits I need for every text in a pandas column

```
def parse_column(text):
    _MATCH_SYSLOG_REGEXP_EXPRESSION: str = r"(\b(?:Jan(?:uary|uar)?|Feb(?:ruary|ruar)?|M(?:a|ä)?r(?:ch|z)?|Apr(?:il)?|Ma(?:y|i)?|Jun(?:e|i)?|Jul(?:y)?|Aug(?:ust)?|Sep(?:tember)?|O(?:c|k)?t(?:ober)?|Nov(?:ember)?|De(?:c|z)(?:ember)?)\b[ ]{1,2}(?:(?:0[1-9])|(?:[12][0-9])|(?:3[01])|[1-9]) (?!<[0-9])(?:2[0123]|[01]?[0-9]):(?:[0-5][0-9])(?::(?:(?:[0-5]?[0-9]|60)(?:[:.,][0-9]+)?))(?![0-9]))( \b(?:[0-9A-Za-z][0-9A-Za-z-]{0,62})(?:\.(?:[0-9A-Za-z][0-9A-Za-z-]{0,62}))*\b)(.*)"
    data_parts = re.split(_MATCH_SYSLOG_REGEXP_EXPRESSION, text)
    return data_parts[1], data_parts[2], data_parts[3]
```

I have a a dataframe that looks similar to this

```
a = {'Full-Log' : ['Sep 16 09:54:50 hou3-co-edg-fw.com %ASA-4-106023: Deny udp src inside:10.106.148.180/48489 dst outside_985:10.225.7.2/1194 by access-group "FC-GLOBAL-OUT,FCVENDORNET-RAYMOND-OUT(2020-09-16_08:45:06)" [0xa39be45b, 0x0]
', 'Sep 16 09:54:50 bfi5-co-edg-fw.com %ASA-4-106023: Deny tcp src inside:10.106.149.201/59734 dst outside_716:10.10.68.70/6662 by access-group "FCVendorNet(2020-09-16_05:27:21)" [0xd2b2f4e9, 0x0]']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=a)
```

I tried just doing this

```
df["Timestamp"], df["host"], df["event"] = df.apply(parse_column)
```

But I get this error

```
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
df[["Timestamp", "host", "event"]]  = pd.DataFrame(df['Full-Log'].apply(parse_column).to_list(), index=df.index)
```

**Result:**

```
print(df)

                                                                                                                                                                                                                    Full-Log        Timestamp                 host                                                                                                                                                                                    event
0  Sep 16 09:54:50 hou3-co-edg-fw.com %ASA-4-106023: Deny udp src inside:10.106.148.180/48489 dst outside_985:10.225.7.2/1194 by access-group "FC-GLOBAL-OUT,FCVENDORNET-RAYMOND-OUT(2020-09-16_08:45:06)" [0xa39be45b, 0x0]  Sep 16 09:54:50   hou3-co-edg-fw.com   %ASA-4-106023: Deny udp src inside:10.106.148.180/48489 dst outside_985:10.225.7.2/1194 by access-group "FC-GLOBAL-OUT,FCVENDORNET-RAYMOND-OUT(2020-09-16_08:45:06)" [0xa39be45b, 0x0]
1                           Sep 16 09:54:50 bfi5-co-edg-fw.com %ASA-4-106023: Deny tcp src inside:10.106.149.201/59734 dst outside_716:10.10.68.70/6662 by access-group "FCVendorNet(2020-09-16_05:27:21)" [0xd2b2f4e9, 0x0]  Sep 16 09:54:50   bfi5-co-edg-fw.com                            %ASA-4-106023: Deny tcp src inside:10.106.149.201/59734 dst outside_716:10.10.68.70/6662 by access-group "FCVendorNet(2020-09-16_05:27:21)" [0xd2b2f4e9, 0x0]
```

Comment: What is `df['Full-Log'].map(parse_column)` supposed to be? A map?

Comment: @justanewb  You can use both `.map` and `.apply` for invoking your `parse_column`. function.  Actually, I also amended to use `.apply` to adhere to your original code.  Anyway, they act the same in this case.

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't need to capture all date format in all possible locales. Split the string using whitespaces.

```
LOGLINE = re.compile(r'((?:[^\s]+\s){2}[^\s]+) ([^\s]+) (.*)')

df = pd.DataFrame([LOGLINE.match(rec).groups() for rec in a['Full-Log']],
                  columns=['Timestamp', 'host', 'event'])
```

```
>>> df
         Timestamp                host                                              event
0  Sep 16 09:54:50  hou3-co-edg-fw.com  %ASA-4-106023: Deny udp src inside:10.106.148....
1  Sep 16 09:54:50  bfi5-co-edg-fw.com  %ASA-4-106023: Deny tcp src inside:10.106.149....
```

Comment: TypeError: string indices must be integers